# How to fix Load more with AsyncTask duplicating data? - android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I've been trying to implement load more with asynctask but for some reason when I scroll down quickly it shows me the same items again. For exp if I scroll down my list has (1, 2, 3, 4) and when I scroll more down and load more items it gives me the same items as the previous one (1, 2, 3, 4).
I hope it is clear enough and if not I could try to explain it better.
Here is my code:

```
private class GetMoreData extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<Item>> {

    private GetMoreData() {}

    protected List<Item> doInBackground(Void... param1VarArgs) {

        return JsonParsingData.searchArticles(keyword,items.size(),20);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final List<Item> param1Info) {
        if (param1Info != null) {


            adapter.setLoadMore(new IloadMore() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore() {
                    if (items.size()<total)
                    {
                        items.add(null);
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size()-1);
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                items.remove(items.size() - 1);
                                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(items.size());

                                int index = 1;
                                int end = index + 20;

                                if(param1Info.size()<20)
                                    end = param1Info.size();

                                for(int i = index;i<end;i++)

                                {
                                    if(param1Info.get(i).getID() != null){

                                        Item item= new Item(param1Info.get(i).getID(),param1Info.get(i).getTitle(),
                                                param1Info.get(i).getImage(), param1Info.get(i).getDatePub(), param1Info.get(i).getLink());
                                        items.add(item);

                                        Log.e("Get More Data ID: "+i+": ", param1Info.get(i).getID());
                                        Log.e("Get More Data Titre: "+i+": ", param1Info.get(i).getTitle());

                                    }

                                }

                                loadMore = true;

                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                adapter.setLoaded();

                                if(items.size() < total && excMore ) {
                                    new GetMoreData().execute();
                                }else
                                    Log.e("Tab 1", "" + excMore );

                            }
                        },10000);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(RechercheActivity.this,"Load data completed !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


}
```

Comment: where are you setting (from,to) items count? If you always same values so you always getting same results

Comment: in here (return JsonParsingData.searchArticles(keyword,items.size(),20);) this way it loads new items because i'm assigning new start each time which is the items size but the problem is sometimes the doInBackground doesn't finish running or something like that.